# Launching SSMS 2014 VsDebugPresentationPackage Error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I am getting this error when trying to launch SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

```
Package VsDebugPresentationPackage did not load correctly.
And in error log:
SetSite failed for package [VsDebugPresentationPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the SSMS with /Log you would be able to find an xml file named "ActivityLog.xml" here:
"C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\10.0"

Going through that file you will find a line which is saying config files is not having the root element. If so, simply remove any sub folder of "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation". Then run SSMS with admin privilege and bingo...

This little solution took 1 day of my sprint...

Comment: Thank you! I too lost hours to this problem.