# Visual Studio debugger isn't configured to debug this unhandled exception

Tags: c#, windows, maui

After `OnApearing()` the App breaks on:

```cs
//On App.g.i.cs
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
    UnhandledException += (sender, e) => //e.Exception = {"No installed components were detected.\r\n"}
    {
         if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
#endif
```

I already looked into output and call stack, checked the threads but nothing stands out to me.

For additional context I redid the model hierarchy, but I initialize all models (synchronously) without issues before the `OnAppearing()`.

When I continue I get this pop up:
[image: 1st pop up]

Out of options I accept the suggestion but then I get a new instance of VS studio and this pop up:
[image: 2nd pop up]
The file ActivityLog.xml doesn't seem to exist, along with the location.

And lastly this one:
[image: 3rd pop up]

Comment: Do you have exception handling inside UpdateUI?

Comment: The code never reached UpdateUI, but no I am not handling exceptions there for now

Comment: I wouldn’t assume that’s true.  Add some exception handling and logging to that method

Comment: I tried to wrap `UpdateUI` content in a try catch but nothing happened I even got a level deeper and wrapped another method content in a try catch but still nothing happened, no break points nor exceptions.

Comment: I even remove all content from the `UpdateUI()`, the issue happens after
`await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(UpdateUI);`but before any step I have access through the debugger., I also call `UpdateUI()` as a regular method and no issues, just when I use that main thread, but before this section of code was working fine... very weird

Comment: Glad that you are able to get this issue around. But I cannot reproduce it. Not sure if it helps : [Launching SSMS 2014 VsDebugPresentationPackage Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820330/launching-ssms-2014-vsdebugpresentationpackage-error)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue is that I added every control twice to the view.